# how can I upload a file from blob storage using logic apps vs azure functions for large files

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I need to use logic app to load some csv files in a files storage in Azure to a blob storage. what trigger to use in logic app to access the files storage in Azure?

The files are quite large up to 1 GB and I'd like to be able to send them to an ftp server or to a restful endpoint for upload (using example PUT verb).

Is logic apps able to do this or would it be better to use Azure functions? Any resources or help pointing me in right direction would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question about which trigger you can use in logic app, it depends on your requirements. If you want the logic app be triggered periodically, you can add a "[Recurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence)" schedule. If you want to trigger it manually, you can [add a request trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger), then you can trigger the logic app by calling the request url.

For your concern about if logic app can do this, I'm a little confused about what you want to do by logic app, you want to load csv files from azure file storage to blob storage in logic app? Or load csv files from blob storage to ftp? Both of them can be implemented by logic app if your files don't exceed its limits.

The "Azure File Storage" connector has general limits below:
[image]

The "Azure Blob Storage" connector also has some general limits, shown as below:
[image]

Ftp connector's limits are shown as below:
[image]

According to the two screenshots above, if your 1 GB files are lots of small files(the number of list blobs can't exceed 5000), your requirements can be implemented in logic app.

If you want to load files from azure file storage to blob storage(your files don't exceed the limits above), you can refer to the logic app below:
[image]

If you want to load files from azure blob storage to ftp(your files don't exceed the limits above), you can refer to the logic app below:
[image]

By the way, I think it is necessary to mention the price of logic app. It is billed by number of actions' execution, we can know more information about logic app price by this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/). So if you have too many files and it will lead to too many action executions in you logic app, you need to notice the cost between logic app and azure function. Maybe function will be cheaper than logic app.