# Excel into Azure Data Factory into SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, dropbox, azure-logic-apps

I read a few threads on this but noticed most are outdated, with excel becoming an integration in 2020.

I have a few excel files stored in Drobox, I would like to automate the extraction of that data into azure data factory, perform some ETL functions with data coming from other sources, and finally push the final, complete table to Azure SQL.

I would like to ask what is the most efficient way of doing so?

Would it be on the basis of automating a logic app to extract the xlsx files into Azure Blob, use data factory for ETL, join with other SQL tables, and finally push the final table to Azure SQL?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using Logic app to extract excel file [Know Issues and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#known-issues-and-limitations) with respect to excel connectors.

If you are importing large files using logic app depending on size of files you are importing consider this thread once - [logic apps vs azure functions for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494534/how-can-i-upload-a-file-from-blob-storage-using-logic-apps-vs-azure-functions-fo)

Just to summarize approach, I have mentioned below steps:

**Step1:** Use Azure Logic app to upload excel files from Dropbox to blob storage

**Step2:** Create data factory pipeline with copy data activity

**Step3:** Use blob storage service as a source dataset.

**Step4:** Create SQL database with required schema.

**Step5:** Do schema mapping

**Step6:** Finally Use SQL database table as sink

Comment: Thank You for this! So if I am understanding correctly, I would make Data Flows for any data manipulation and uploading to SQL. then I would include that inside my Pipeline and run?

Comment: Yes, for practical understanding you can refer below 2 threads for data manupulation in data flow
Link1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440669/handle-null-values-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline/68497127#68497127
Link2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376882/using-datafactory-to-copy-documents-from-one-container-to-another-and-adding-a-p/68482852#68482852

Comment: I like this approach because I'm facing the same problem. But, right now, in particular case, excel file has some custom request, ex: have data in some sheets. So, ADF can read data from multiple sheets ?

Comment: @Daleman you can use a lookup activity on excel sheet, and use the lookup output in a ForEach activity. The ForEach activity iterates over the sheet names, passing them to a parameterized dataset to copy every other sheet.